# Is "we contribute ..." bad style in scientific writing?

Tags: writing-style, scientific-language

In my paper I am writing a couple of times

> We contribute ...

for example

> First, we contribute a new definition for the problem and then a formula for xy.

My editor has removed all the "contribute" and replaced them with the verb "present". I have also seen such sentences with "introduce" or "propose".

I chose "contribute", because I wanted to make clear what our new contributions to the topic are what is not. E.g. I am repeating some formulas from other papers.

Is "we contribute ..." bad style and if so, why?

Comment: As a matter of _English_, there isn’t a whole lot of difference, especially since you include the word “new”. If the question was asked on [academia.se], you might get more feedback regarding norms and nuances of such terms in academia.

Comment: I think that it is poor style and possibly wrong. Your paper is offered for assessment, yet you are claiming a contribution to something - this would mean that the contribution is indeed the truth. You are not doing this. You are introducing a concept to the reader or proposing something to the reader.

Comment: @Lawrence: Thanks for the tip. I just looked, seems Academia has a tag "writing-style".

Comment: @Greybeard: Convincing point, thanks! But, why do we then have a section "Contributions" in each paper, instead of "Propositions" or something like that?

Comment: You’re welcome. Have a look at their help pages for what’s on topic. They don’t specialise in writing styles, but I think the question you’ve asked should be on topic there.

Comment: @Lawrence: Should the post be moved there? If so, how?

Comment: I’d recommend migration. Raise a flag to ask a moderator to help.

Comment: @Greybeard: So, after the paper is accepted, I can write "contribute" in the final version?

Comment: No. I would still avoid it. Your accepted paper is still new to each new reader who should be allowed to judge it on its merits.

Answer (score 1):

The word *contribute* has particular meaning in scientific publications. It is important to use the words expected in academic articles. Someone scanning your paper may be looking out for the word "contribution" as this is the keyword that states the motivation for you publishing your paper.  I would just reword it to: "this work's main contribution is".

Comment: In conclusion, you think, one should avoid using "we contribute", but rephrase to "... contribution..."? Doesn't that make the text more clunky? Note, that in the introduction I have a section "Contribution". I was using "we contribute" additionally throughout the main, theoretical part later.

Comment: If you have already highlighted your contribution in the introduction, then I agree with the other posters.  There is no reason to keep using the word "contribute" throughout.